# RecyclerView does not work when an additional LinearLayout it added

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

There is an outer LinearLayout in main_activity.xml. This has two buttons and another LinearLayout with ID linlay. In linlay, a fragment(which contains a recyclerview with linearlayout manager set) is called on first button click. This works perfectly fine.But when i try to club the two buttons into another LinearLayout(horizontal), the recycler does not appear in the linlay.
This works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/contact_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
  
    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But this does not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/contact_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="96dp">

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Change layout_height of the horizontal LinearLayout to wrap_content, there is no space for linlay.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @i_A_mok, the issue is due to the match parent value of layout_height attribute of the additional linear layout.